# spread operator does not seem to copy full object

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to implement express error handling middleware.  It is working but I don't understand why I have to set `error.message` equal to the `err.message` after I copy `err` to `error`.  Is the spread operator not copying all the attributes from `err`?  When I inspect the err object I don't even see a message or a stack attribute.  Also, why is it able to log the error message before the error message is created in the if block.

This is how I am extending the Error

```js
// src/utils/errorResponse.js

class ErrorResponse extends Error {
  constructor(message, statusCode) {
    super(message)
    this.statusCode = statusCode
  }
}
module.exports = ErrorResponse
```

Custom error handler middleware

```js
// src/middleware/error.js

const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse')

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  let error = { ...err } 
  console.log({ error.message }) // undefined
  error.message = err.message
  console.log({ error.message }) // `Resource not found with id of ${err.value}`

  // Log to console for dev
  // console.log(error.stack)

  // Mongoose bad ObjectId
  if (err.name === 'CastError') {
    const message = `Resource not found with id of ${err.value}`
    error = new ErrorResponse(message, 404)
  } else {
    console.log(error.name)
  }

  res.status(error.statusCode || 500).json({
    success: false,
    error: error.message || 'Server Error',
  })
}

module.exports = errorHandler
```

I trigger the error by making a get request with a bad ObjectID

```js
// src/controllers/bootcamp.js

const Bootcamp = require('../models/Bootcamp')

...

// @desc Get single bootcamp
// @route GET /api/v1/bootcamps/:id
// @access Public
exports.getBootcamp = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id)
    if (!bootcamp) {
      return next(err)
    }
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: bootcamp })
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the `err` parameter you're getting is of Error type object and message key is present in prototype of Error object and spread operator shallow copies keys of object ( excluding prototype keys )

Statement for spread operator from mdn -

The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (ES2018) added spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

Shallow-cloning `(excluding prototype)` or merging of objects is now possible using a shorter syntax than Object.assign().

For reference -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Spread Syntax copies only enumerable properties(The ones that are set to **true**).

The properties in the Error object like `error.stack` and `error.message` are not enumerable(They are set to **false**), and so they are not copied. You can check this with the snippet below:

```js
const myError = new Error('Something went wrong');
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myError));
```

The purpose of this is because objects have many more properties, especially from inheritance like: toString(), hasOwnProperty(). You wouldn't want these properties to be iterated over when you call `For..in` loop or `Object.keys`. So the enumeration for such properties is set to false.